# UIStackView adjust height to subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uistackview

I want the UIStackView to resize to fit their subviews (UIImageView and UILabel in this case)

```
    let headerView = UIStackView()
    headerView.axis = .vertical
    headerView.alignment  = .center
    headerView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    headerView.spacing = 10

    let headerImage = UIImageView(...)
    headerImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    headerImage.clipsToBounds = true
    headerImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.width / 1.618)

    let desciptionView = UILabel()
    desciptionView.text = "Some very long text wrapping multiple lines..."
    desciptionView.numberOfLines = 0
    desciptionView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)

    headerView.addArrangedSubview(headerImage)
    headerView.addArrangedSubview(desciptionView)

    print(headerView.bounds) // always 0,0,0,0
    print(headerView.frame) // always 0,0,0,0

    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

(in this code height and width are 0)

How to implement the wanted behaviour?

Comment: `headerView.alignment  = .fill`?

Comment: I hope that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254889/uistackview-distribution-fill-equally/40256540#40256540) -somehow- helps you.

Comment: Your views are being collapsed because there are no constraints on them that keep their original frames intact. Try adding some `NSLayoutConstraints` to the views in your stack view.

Comment: Which Constrains are necessary?

Answer (score 8):

The only way I have found to do this is by setting the content hugging and compression resistance priorities of the child views to be required, something like this:

```
    let arrangedViews = [filterLabel, image]
        .map { (view: UIView) -> UIView in
            view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
            view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
            return view }

    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedViews)
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.distribution = .fill
    stack.spacing = 8
```

With those set on the arranged subviews, do you do indeed (or at least I did) get the desired result.

Comment: Just in case you have height constraint for stackview, have to set its priority to 500. But this is a good answer and should be marked as a correct answer