# Hide view without whitespace

Tags: ios, swift, view, hide

WPF contains **Hidden** (hides the control, but reserves the space it occupies in the layout) and **Collapsed** (does not render the control and does not reserve the whitespace)

*Swift* contains **isHidden** property only (myView.isHidden = true).
How can I hide my control without whitespace?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. You would have to remove it from the parent.  `view.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup: No, your comment is not correct. There is a way to do this. @ kirill you can use UIStackView for achieving this

Comment: May be this tutorial help you to understand about UIStackView usage: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: @Midhun MP , thanks for the link!

Comment: What about using a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview)? [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254889/uistackview-distribution-fill-equally/40256540#40256540) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using storyboards and constraints, one clever way that I've found is to set the width or height constraint of the disappearing view to 0.

As an example:

[image: a special alt-text present for you, curious reader! it's beer!]

```
@IBAction func onTapSquare(_ sender: Any) {
  let constraint = disappearingView.constraintForIdentifier(id: "example_width")
  constraint?.constant = 0
}
```

Note that you have to write the `constraintForIdentifier` function yourself, you can copy/paste from my view extension here:
[Github link!](https://github.com/elliotfiske/disappearing-constraint-example/blob/master/DisappearingConstraints/View%2BUtil.swift)

I whipped up a tiny example project which you can grab here:
[Disappearing Constraint Example](https://github.com/elliotfiske/disappearing-constraint-example)

If you've got margin in between the views, you can set that to 0 with a similar method. Good luck!

Here it is in action:
[image: gif of it in action]