# UIStackview align left

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'm trying to align the items in UIStackview horizontally to the left.

Is there anyway to do this programmatically? I tried to do this via storyboard but was not successful. For some reason, the items in the UIStackView centers itself.

Comment: I hope [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40256540/5501940) to useful to you. You need apply the same approach but horizontally instead of vertically.

Answer (score 28):

If you use StackView setting axis property to "Horizontal",
I think you can't align it to the left.

But there is a way to make it left visually.

1. set StackView leading constraint with "equal" relationship
2. set StackView trailing constraint with "greater than or equal"

like this

```
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: This worked for me to get items to align left with desired spacing between items.

Comment: Great solution! If you're working with storyboard and constraints, you will have some issues. Just put a placeholder that you remove at runtime to hide this issue.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but if we want to align elements to the left it should be lessThanOrEqual

Answer (score 14):

Try Adding One Space View in Your Stack View , Like this

```
 // To Make Our Buttons aligned to left We have added one spacer view
    UIButton *spacerButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [spacerButton setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [spacerButton setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.buttonsStackView addArrangedSubview:spacerButton];
```

And Make

```
self.buttonsStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFill;
```

Comment: I found just adding an empty UIView works fine

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @Ankit Maurya, solution with example for swift

```
 let stackView = UIStackView()
 stackView.axis = .horizontal
 stackView.distribution = .fill
 
 let spacer = UIView()
 spacer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
 spacer.setContentHuggingPriority(.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)
 spacer.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)

 // stackView.addArrangedSubview.... any u need
 stackView.addArrangedSubview(spacer)
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2** + **iOS 12.1** tested:

```
    let stackView: UIStackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .leading // <- aligns each of your items to the left. 

    // further setup + setup constraints
    // ...
```

Comment: stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
this one helped to have clean log without uisv-spacing warnings about broken constraints

Comment: Is `leading` alignment is not available when setting in storyboard?

Comment: @Hemang I can answer your question. I'm only building my views in code. But you could do the following. Create your stack view via storyboard and link it to your code and configure the stack view in code rather in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @BaranEmre for the tip.

Comment: .leading works only with .vertical, but the question is about horizontal

Comment: Use .contentMode = .left  to align all the elements in UIStackView to left with horizontal axis

Answer (score 2):

Use the `UIStackView.alignment` property.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview/1616243-alignment

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. As simple as `stack.alignment = .leading`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice guys. I tried playing with the options on UIStackView.alignment but it never really worked as desired. In the end I messed with the width of the UIStackView to achieve the desired results.

```
if(prdDTO.getShellIcn() == "Y")
    {
        let icon = UIImageView()
        icon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shellfish")
        prdIngredients.addArrangedSubview(icon)
        stackviewWidth += 25
    }

    if(prdDTO.getVegeIcn() == "Y")
    {
        let icon = UIImageView()
        icon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Vege")
        prdIngredients.addArrangedSubview(icon)
        stackviewWidth += 25
    }

    if(prdDTO.getSpicyIcn() == "Y")
    {
        let icon = UIImageView()
        icon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Spicy")
        prdIngredients.addArrangedSubview(icon)
        stackviewWidth += 25
    }

    prdIngredients.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(stackviewWidth))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing constrant (even though XCode complains!!!) and your problem will be solved. This will cause the the view to expand as you add items to it.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

### Storyboard

1. Click `Attributes Inspector`
2. Select `Trailing` from the Drop Down menu when `Alignment` is selected.

### Programmatically

1. Change the `UIStackView.alignment` property when initializing.