# How to hide view graphically while maintaining presence in stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I currently have a stack view that is `horizontal`, `fill`, `fill equally`. Inside, there are 3 generic views with different coloured backgrounds.

[image]

My current problem is that, when I set one of the views inside to `hidden=true`, the other two views immediately expands to fill the void. I don't want this. All I want is for the space to remain blank and the target view to be "invisible" both graphically and to UI input events.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIStackView Distribution Fill Equally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254889/uistackview-distribution-fill-equally). It is the same case, but vertical instead of horizontal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting `isHidden=true` you could set `view.alpha = 0` to make it invisible and also `view.isUserInteractionEnabled=false` to disable UI input events.

*As @robmayoff pointed out below the `isUserInteractionEnabled=false` is not actually required.

Comment: You don't have to change `isUserInteractionEnabled`. If the view's `alpha` is 0, it automatically ignores touch events.

Comment: That would be also a workaround (as a trick). You could do it without any cheating :) please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254889/uistackview-distribution-fill-equally/40256540#40256540

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your screenshot, you are using the constraints. So, when the element hides, collapses and the other expand.

Use 'opaque' flag to make it invisible.

Comment: That is not the effect of the `opaque` (in Swift, `isOpaque`) property.

Comment: That would be also a workaround (as a trick). You could do it without any cheating :) please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254889/uistackview-distribution-fill-equally/40256540#40256540