# UIStackView shift content to left when inner views are hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I've 3 buttons inside a horizontal stack view. I want to shift buttons to left if one or two buttons are hidden. It's basically left shift operation. I've tried few options with stack view in storyboard but not sure if I'm on right track.

How to do it in stack view or otherwise?

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254889/uistackview-distribution-fill-equally/40256540#40256540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the stackview trailing constraint while hide the button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackViewTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint!

func hideButton(button: UIButton) -> Void {
     button.isHidden = true

     stackViewTrailing.constant += button.frame.width
}
```

Comment: Though it's not a good way to achieve the goal, it may have worked for you. But keep in mind that **stack view wasn't introduced to work like this**

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stack view with NO constraints set, the size of the stack view is that of its contents. Lets say the brackets [] were your stack view and X represents your buttons, if you give the stack view only a leading constraint, a vertical constraint of any kind and set the distribution to "Fill Equally" it will behave as follows:

---8px---[X X X X]

remove/hide one button:

---8px---[X X X]

This sounds like the behaviour you are seeking.

Another note: If the buttons are not distributed equally by your stack view even though you have its distribution set to "Fill Equally", make sure to give your first button (or more) a width and height constraint.

Comment: Yes this is what I want to achieve. However if I don't pin it to right then it will not fill equally. I want to keep it equal when three buttons are shown and shift left when buttons are hidden.

Comment: You mean the buttons are not filled equally inside the stack view across the entire device screen? That is why you have to pin the stack view to the left and to the right? What you want to do is against the stack views nature.

However you could do a somewhat whacky workaround by inserting an empty UIView at the end of the stack view whenever a button was hidden, and removing any empty UIView when a button is shown again.

Otherwise you will have to make do without a stack view and have them each use constraints to touch the UIButton left of them.

Comment: @Dan - it's the actual way of using `UIStackView`.

Answer (score 0):

Take an IBOutlet Connection to your buttons. Now put some conditions on your buttons. And when these conditions are met, you can set the alignment of your button to left. Try this programmatically.

```
// These are IBOUtlet Collections
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var hideButtons: [UIButton]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  configureButtons()
}

private func configureButtons() {
  for (index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
    button.tag = index
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
  for (index, button) in hideButtons.enumerated() {
    button.tag = index
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hidePressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("Show", for: .selected)
  }
}

@objc private func hidePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
  sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

  buttons[sender.tag].isHidden = sender.isSelected

  var totalHiddenCount = 0
  for button in buttons {
    if button.isHidden == true {
      totalHiddenCount += 1
    }
  }
  for button in buttons {
    if totalHiddenCount >= 2 {
      button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    } else {
      button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
   }
  }
 }

@objc private func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {}
```

[image]

Comment: It does work if I hide two buttons and show only one button. If I hide middle button then 3rd button doesn't shit left.

Comment: Check the stack view's aignment also.

Comment: Stack view is pinned to left and right, something to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. Follow the below steps.

1) First provide the proper `Constrain` for the `StackView` after the setup your all 3 images into it.

2) Then give a fixed width to the stack view.And create the `StackView Constrain Width` Outlet. Check the image.

```
@IBOutlet var discardWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

[image]

3) Count the `StackView width` with the `2 images`. In my case the width of `stackView with 3 images` is `100px` and with `2 images` it is `69px`.

4) Coding as follow.

```
     if // **Your Condition** {
            img1.isHidden = true
            discardWidth.constant = 69
        } else {
            img1.isHidden = false
            discardWidth.constant = 100
```

Simple Right. Its just show you proper image without the stretching image. Check below image.

[image]